# Self-calling controller with weard option ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm building ASP.NET Core 3.1 app and  I got a problem. When I run my application, I have the home controller running and immediately after it the controller is called to process a specific request(by clicking on the link, the controller gets the name of the category). I've already checked a bunch of times, I don't call it manually, and this controller gets a parameter I don't understand. What is "favicon", and how to fix it?
[Here you can check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjdLY.png)

Comment: How did you call the get action?I could call it by clicking the link `<a asp-action="GetBooks" asp-route-name="aaa">aaaaaaa</a>` and it works well.I suggest that you could share a sample which could reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [favicon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Favicon) is automatically requested by a browser to display an icon for the page.

It appears your method is matching that request at the root of your app. To avoid this, make your controller action [route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1) more specific, for example:

```
[HttpGet("books/{name}")]
```

With a request like:

```
https://myapp.com/books/atlas-shrugged
```